# List not appending

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I need to open a .txt file and iterate through it looking for a palindrome. My loop will iterate through the file but is not returning anything even though I know that there are palindromes in the file. It will only print out a bunch of empty brackets when I run it.

```
file = open("dictionary.txt", "r") 
lst = [] 
for word in file: 
    if(len(word) > 1 and word == word[::-1]): 
        lst = lst.append(word) 
    print(lst)
```

Comment: Replace this line of code: `lst = lst.append(word)` to this : `lst.append(word)`

Comment: post your text file

Comment: `lst = lst.append(word) ` is a problem, but since you didn't get any error there is a problem with the file input as well, you should probably call `strip()`.

Comment: @Ahmad Farhan The text file has like 4,500 lines. I know that it has a palindrome tho.

Comment: I fixed that line before I even posted this, I guess I forgot to post the newest version of what I have like a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `strip` your string. Moreover, `append` modifies the original list and returns `None`.

```
file = open("dictionary.txt", "r") 
lst = [] 
for word in file:
    word=word.strip()
    if(len(word) > 1 and word == word[::-1]): 
        lst.append(word) 
print(lst)
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. Stripping the string did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

`lst.append(word)` appends the word to the `list` and doesn't return anything.
Your code `lst = lst.append(word)` is appending the word to `lst` and overwriting it by assigning `None` which is returned by `append`.

Answer (score 1):

You're indeed appending correctly, but getting the return value of the append statement, which is nonsense.

Replace the following line:

```
lst = lst.append(word)
```

by

```
lst.append(word)
```

And that's all.

Comment: That is what I thought. My problem now is that when I run the program it is not printing off the palindromes that I know are there. Does that mean there is a problem with my file input?

Comment: You need to strip your words. Because of the way you're reading your file(line by line using file's iterator) your `word` variable has an endline character.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the content of the file to a variable

```
var = file.read()
```